# Generate table of all main languages

Tags: google-api

I have to create a list with all languages which should look like this:

```
Col 1   |   Col 2
-----------------
English |  English
German  |  Deutsch
French  |  Français
Spanish |  Español
...
```

**Col 1:**  Language in English

**Col 2:**  Original Country Language

The list should cover all main languages (or in other words: all languages which you can translate in google translator)
Of course this takes quite a while.

Is it possible to generate this list with a script by using the Google API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, google has a [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) which is very similar to the Google Translator. There are a couple of endpoints which are of interest to you in this case.

There is a way to list all the available languages, which would populate your Col 1. By default, this returns all the language (and sometimes language-country) codes that are supported, [but you can provide a `target` query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/discovering-supported-languages#listing_supported_languages_in_target_language) to also include the name of the language in a "target language". In your case, you would want to show it "en-US".

In theory, you *could* repeat this for every language code and then just use the result for the language's own language code to populate Col 2. (This may be the most accurate way, but you'll get back a lot of extra data you don't want.)

Of course, you can also just [translate the text](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) to get your Col 2 results.